# cuDF - groupby UDF to support datetime

Tags: numba, numba-pro, cudf

I have a cuDF dataframe with following columns:

```
columns = ["col1", "col2", "dt"]
```

The (`dt`) in the form of `datetime64[ns]`.

I would like to write a UDF to apply to each group in this dataframe, and get max of `dt` for each group. Here is what I am trying, but seems like `numba` doesn't support the `datetime64[ns]` values in UDFs.

```
def f1(dt, out):
   l = len(dt)
   maxvalue = dt[0]
   for i in  range(cuda.threadIdx.x, l, cuda.blockDim.x):
      if dt[i] > maxvalue:
         maxvalue = dt[i]
   out[:0] = maxvalue

gdf = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"], method="cudf")
df = gdf.apply_grouped(f1, incols={"dt": "dt"}, outcols=dict(out=numpy.datetime64))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at 0x7effda063510>)
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (10)
```

I have similar functions, which work fine with integers and floats. Does it mean that numba doesnt support datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

`Apply_groups` won't give you what I think you're after, which is groupby on max `dt`.  You needed to use `aggs` with max on `dt`.  cudf's groupby functions would have done the rest. To get your values in `datetime64[ms]`, you use `astype()`, and save it back to the dataframe (very fast).
 See my example:

```
import cudf
a = cudf.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "col2": [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1], "dt": [10000000, 2000000, 3000000, 100000, 2000000, 40000000]}) 
a['dt'] = a['dt'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(a)
a['dt'] = a['dt'].astype('datetime64[ms]')
print(a)
gdf = a.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).agg({'dt':'max'})
print(gdf.head())
```

`dt` column values would be formatted to between 0.1-40 milliseconds as nanoseconds from Jan 1st, 1970, giving you a print out of

```
   col1  col2                         dt
0     1     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.010000
1     1     2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.002000
2     1     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.003000
3     2     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000100
4     2     2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.002000
5     2     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.040000

   col1  col2                      dt
0     1     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.010
1     1     2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.002
2     1     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.003
3     2     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
4     2     2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.002
5     2     1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.040

                               dt
col1 col2                        
1    1    1970-01-01 00:00:00.010
     2    1970-01-01 00:00:00.002
2    1    1970-01-01 00:00:00.040
     2    1970-01-01 00:00:00.002
```